# Perl performance hit between two common regex methods for string trimming?

Tags: regex, perl

So I'm working on a Perl script that does a large amount of processing (nothing too complicated, but *lots* of it) and decided to do a little benchmark to compare two common methods of trimming strings.

The first method is a quick one-liner:

```
$word =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;
```

The second method is a little longer, but does the same thing:

```
$word =~ s/^\s+//;
$word =~ s/\s+$//;
```

For my benchmarks, I had the script read from a file with 40 million lines, trimming each (does nothing other than that).  The average line length is under 20 bytes.

The first method took on average 87 seconds to complete.
The second method took on average 27 seconds to complete.
Doing no processing (just read line, continue) takes an average 16 seconds.

The first method (first pass) will match either all the leading or trailing whitespace, then remove it, then match and remove the leading/trailing whitespace on the other side.
The second method matches and removes all leading whitespace, then matches and removes all trailing whitespace.

Maybe I'm in the wrong here, but why would the second method be over 3x faster than the first?

Comment: I can't see method one working in the case where there is both leading and trailing space.

Comment: @MetaEd: It should work, due to the `g`.

Comment: can you benchmark with the `s///o` modifier? E.g. `$regex = qr/^\s+/o`

Comment: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=602

Comment: @sehe can you go into a bit more detail?  I read up on `qr//` but I'm not too sure how to apply it.  `$r = qr/^\s+/o; $word =~ s/$q/;`?

Comment: @Mat yes, that's well and all, but that still doesn't answer the question of *why*.

Comment: @GigaWatt: basically (modulo two typos). However, simply add `//o;` where it says `//;` now

Comment: @GigaWatt: I know, that's why it's a comment. Just pointing out that there are "prettier" of writing that, and that it is sort of an informal de-facto standard.

Comment: @sehe m//o is a no-op for this pattern, it will not change anything. m//o is (used to be) useful when there are variables in the pattern. There are no variables in this pattern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It makes a sense that anchored non-backtracking patterns can be optimized WAY better (effectively a single forward/backward sequential scan starting from a known character position);

Chances are that the 'option' (|) makes the optimizer back off and you get standard backtracking, quite badly so, because many spaces might occur that are not trailing

Comment: The first one also has to check the string up-to 3 times, because of the required `/g` option.

Comment: @BradGilbert: If I interpret the output of James's suggestion right, it will not actually attempt more than two matches, since the second match will have left of at the EOL state. However, the time spent doing a dumb linear match scan is wasted. The 'optimized' version effectively _guesses_ the start of the potential match, skipping all the intermediate matching

Comment: The `/g` option continues to try to match until it fails. If a string starts and ends with white-space, it doesn't fail to match until the third time through.

Comment: @BradGilbert: the point is that it fails due to starting at an EOL node. That is not impacting performance.

Comment: I agree that it probably isn't a large impact, but it still has to check. Which at the very least has to do a comparison, and a conditional jump. It is more likely that there is at least one subroutine call. Which means pushing registers on the stack, and popping them back off of the stack. ( I would like to point out that you didn't disagree that it has to do that check 3 times. )

Comment: Actually I've written more assembly programs, than C programs, and never any C++.

Answer (score 11):

The regex engine is having to do more work in the first case namely in backtracking to evaluate alternatives.  You can see the difference in the code involved:

```
echo " hello " |perl -Mre=debug -ple 's/^\s+|\s+$//g'
echo " hello " |perl -Mre=debug -ple 's/^\s+//;s/\s+$//'
```

Comment: welcome  to StackOverflow, you have my +1 for quite a nice condensed answer. Thanks for posting - even though you were a bit late to the party :)

Comment: That's hella nifty.  Mind explaining those flags?

Comment: The '-M' specifies the module just like you would write 'use module'.  Here we are writing 'use re qw(debug)' The '-p' creates a block that looks like 'while (<>)...print'; The '-l' adds a newline to print().  After the read and before the print() the code you want to execute is automatically added.  If you don't want an unconditional print() for every line read, use the '-n' switch in lieu of '-p'.  See [link](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html)

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that the Perl regular expression may be able to optimize the second version by using a static analysis of the pattern. For example it might see that `/^foo/` must match at the start of the string. If the match fails there, there is no point in iterating over the rest of the characters in the string checking for matches.

> By default, the "^" character is guaranteed to match only the beginning of the string, the "$" character only the end (or before the newline at the end), and **Perl does certain optimizations** with the assumption that the string contains only one line.

[Source](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions) (Emphasis mine.)

The first version is a more complicated expression and is not so easily optimized.